# In python, using socket programming how to show data received at client end?

Tags: python, json, sockets

I am facing an issue in showing data on the client-side. Here I am validating data using MySQL database and when the data is valid, from the 2nd database the appropriate data will send to the client end. It is sending on client-end but not showing anything.
server-side.py

```
import mysql.connector as mysql # This module is used to connect python with MySQL database 
import socket
import sys 
import json

mydb1=mysql.connect(
        user = 'rajat',
        passwd = 'rajat',
        host = 'localhost',
        database = 'myforum'
        )
def server_program():
    HOST = '192.168.0.115' #this is your localhost
    PORT = 8888
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    #socket.socket: must use to create a socket.
    #socket.AF_INET: Address Format, Internet = IP Addresses.
    #socket.SOCK_STREAM: two-way, connection-based byte streams.
    # Binding socket with post and host.
    try:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error as err:
        sys.exit()
    #listen(): This method sets up and start TCP listener. 
    s.listen(10)
    print ('Socket is now listening')
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        df1 = conn.recv(1024)
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        df7 = conn.recv(1024)
        df8 = json.loads(df7)
        df2 = list(df8.values())        
        # This is mysql database which is connected with python.
        #Here we need user,host,password and database name to connect with python
        mycursor1=mydb1.cursor()
        mycursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM form_simpleform WHERE id=1")# Its a mysql query which is selecting all fields from table where id is equals to one.
        df3=mycursor1.fetchone()
        if df2 == (list(df3)):
            print('Yes Data Exists')
            # Here is the 2nd database which is used when data is valid. 
            #If data is valid, it extracts the valid data of that id and send back the data to the client.
            mydb2=mysql.connect(
            user = 'rajat',
            passwd = 'rajat',
            host = 'localhost',
            database = 'after_validation'
            )
            mycursor2 = mydb2.cursor()
            mycursor2.execute("SELECT * FROM android_display_data WHERE id=2")
            df4 = mycursor2.fetchone()

            conn.send(str(df4).encode('utf-8'))
            conn.close()#Here the data is send to the client side.  json.dumps(df4).encode('utf-8')
            print("Data is sent to the client ")
            break
        else:
            print('Invalid Data')
            break
    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_program()
```

Client-side.py

```
import socket
import sys
import json
def client_prog():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('192.168.0.115', 8888))
    for args in sys.argv:
        if args == '':
            args = 'no args'
        else:
            df1 = 'connected'
            s.sendall(df1.encode('utf-8'))
            print("done")

            df5 = s.recv(1024)          
            print(df5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client_prog()
```

Output from server-side.py

```
C:\Users\Pallavai\DJANGO PROJECTS\Socket>python Server-Side.py
Socket is now listening
Yes Data Exists
Data is sent to the client
```

output from client-side.py

```
C:\Users\Pallavai\DJANGO PROJECTS\Socket>python client-sidetxt.py
done
b''
```

How to show data on client side which is in b''. I tried pickle, json, str method to do it. But it was not working. Your help will be appriciated.

Comment: You may want to print `str(df4)` on the server side. An usual way of testing sockets is to send `Hello` as a first attempt. Also note that streams are streams, there is no guarantee that you receive a complete "message" in a single step.

Comment: Probably there is no data in `df5`

Comment: You may want to replace `conn.send(str(df4).encode('utf-8'))` with `conn.sendall(str(df4).encode('utf-8'))` to be consistent between your server and client.

As @tevemadar said, `print(str(df4))` before sending it. The likely cause is that it's sending nothing because df4 doesn't contain anything if your query `mycursor2.execute("SELECT * FROM android_display_data WHERE id=2")` isn't returning anything.

Comment: ('2', 'VJ', 'VJ123@gmail.com', 1234567890) 
this is the data which is printing from df4. As you said I tried using print(str(df4))  but it is still showing b '' only. No data is shown on client side.

Comment: you should check `print(df4)` i server. You print `Yes Data Exists` after checking `df2 == (list(df3))` but you never check if `df4` has data.